# NP combination puzzle (Klotski)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-game-theory

I've written a C++ program to solve sliding puzzles games such as UnblockMe and Car Parking. I'm quite happy about it, since it solves various schemes in less than a second. Recently I fed the game with Klotski schema (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klotski) that requires no less than 81 moves to solve it. My code respects the following algorithm:

```
Enqueue the current board
while Q not empty:
    Dequeue a board and examine it if not already examined
    can the big block escape?
        "solution found"
    it cant?
        for each possible board that can arise out of this one
            add board to END of Q
```

With my surprise things go well for about 45-50 moves, then the process is extremly slow. I know the game is NP-complex, but I have the suspect my code could be wrong. **Considering all pieces different**, how many permutation are possible? My code output the following in about one second:

```
step 1 new: 6 duplicated: 0
step 2 new: 14 duplicated: 14
step 3 new: 25 duplicated: 46
step 4 new: 38 duplicated: 112
step 5 new: 63 duplicated: 213
step 6 new: 107 duplicated: 378
step 7 new: 160 duplicated: 659
step 8 new: 239 duplicated: 1094
step 9 new: 332 duplicated: 1750
step 10 new: 491 duplicated: 2665
step 11 new: 668 duplicated: 4009
step 12 new: 804 duplicated: 5897
step 13 new: 853 duplicated: 8226
step 14 new: 869 duplicated: 10534
step 15 new: 869 duplicated: 12813
step 16 new: 918 duplicated: 14921
step 17 new: 955 duplicated: 17058
step 18 new: 1003 duplicated: 19174
step 19 new: 1097 duplicated: 21343
step 20 new: 1215 duplicated: 23674
step 21 new: 1267 duplicated: 26391
step 22 new: 1272 duplicated: 29299
step 23 new: 1493 duplicated: 32276
step 24 new: 1561 duplicated: 35949
step 25 new: 1624 duplicated: 39871
step 26 new: 1595 duplicated: 43830
step 27 new: 1693 duplicated: 47669
step 28 new: 1940 duplicated: 51725
step 29 new: 2280 duplicated: 56435
step 30 new: 2816 duplicated: 62037
step 31 new: 3166 duplicated: 69297
step 32 new: 3420 duplicated: 77335
step 33 new: 4166 duplicated: 85621
step 34 new: 5490 duplicated: 95771
step 35 new: 7398 duplicated: 109271
step 36 new: 9630 duplicated: 127499
step 37 new: 12538 duplicated: 151293
step 38 new: 16240 duplicated: 182497
step 39 new: 20068 duplicated: 223457
```

Last line i.e. `step 39 new: 20068 duplicated: 223457` tells me that with 39 moves player can reach 223457 + 20068 possible disposition of pieces (but 223457 positions are already analized, so availabe also with less moves).

Are these numbers legit? Or I am missing something?

[image]

Comment: Please visit [Andreas Rottler's site](http://www.bricks-game.de/index0.html) for a continuously developed/maintained version of Klotski (called *Bricks*). My son is quite good at this game :-) Warning: Don't advertise computer solvers there - they are understandably frowned upon (though most of the level designs are seeking to be "solver proof").

Comment: A comment on general structure of such programs (I think I did 2x2x2 Rubik's cube or some such at one point). My recollection is that you can easily waste a lot of time searching the list of already visited positions  in vain. That list grows fast and searching it then becomes the bottle neck. The observation I wanted to make is that when you are checking "new" positions that you can reach (in a single move) starting from a position that was reached in $n$ moves, then you need not recheck positions that were reached in less than $n-1$ moves.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen that's exactly what I've done. I keep track of visited nodes as you can see from my output.

Comment: Also, you may benefit from using a quickly computable "hash" function. If you instead of building a single list, build 1024 separate lists according to the value of this 10-bit hash (may be an 8-bit hash suffices?), then those lists remain shorter (by a factor somewhat smaller than 1024 but considerable anyway), and search is significantly faster.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen board is represented with n integers where n is the number of pieces.visited boards are stored in an unsorted set and hashing function is from boost library (hash_combine). checking if a move is possible and make a move is just few operation on bitboards. I was careful to do everything extremly efficient. I have no many other cards to play :S

Comment: I don't know how quickly that library can search an unsorted set. A generic search from an unsorted set sounds less than optimal here. Also, I'm not sure that we were talking about the same thing earlier. What I meant is the following: When you pick a position that is *new* in round 27 (one of those 1693). And then you make a move from that position. You want to decide whether this is new (one of 1940 in round 28). You should not have to search among positions other than the 1595+1693 positions that were new in rounds 26 and 27.

Comment: (cont'd) Hashed or not, there is a big difference in searching from a set of all previously visited positions and only those visited recently. If this is what you are doing, then I apologize for the confusion. The key here is that moves in basic Klotski are reversible.

Comment: Undoubtedly you have profiled your code and know which steps consume the cycles.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if I well understand, you pointed out an interesting thing, but I'm not actually sure about its correctness. It's really just enought to check if a board reached with n moves is already visited just looking at boards reached with n-1 moves? (actually unsorted set, with a good hashing function, finds an element in O(1), so I don't think this is the bottleneck)

Comment: It was about the step $n\to n+1$. Assume that A) a position $P$ can be reached from the starting position $S$ in $n$ moves but not less. B) Another position $P'$ can be reached from $P$ in a single move. My claim is that $P'$ is unreachable from $S$ in $t<n-1$ moves. The reason is that in usual Klotski the move $P\to P'$ is reversible, so $P$ could then also be reached from $S$ in $t+1<n$ moves (via $P'$). A contradiction. In Andreas Rottler's version this is not necessarily true, because the special elements create irreversible moves, but that's beside the point.

Comment: But it is news to me that set membership could be checked in $O(1)$ time. Your universe is combinations of $n$ integers. That is $2^{32n}$ vectors of (assuming $32$-bit integers). True, here you get away with less than 32 bits, but I'm afraid I have a hard time believing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26305/discussion-between-kuket15-and-jyrki-lahtonen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are considering all pieces distinct (even pieces of the same size), then sure, your number of possible arrangements seems reasonable, although it's hard to know for sure. What I can say is that you have four $1 \times 1$ pieces and four $2 \times 1$ pieces. If you make them all distinct, this could increase the number of possible boards by a large multiplicative factor. For example, just assuming you could permute the four $1 \times 1$ pieces for any board configuration, this would mean that the number of possible boards would be multiplied by 24. You'll probably be better off if you label the pieces lexicographically if you must label them (i.e., top-most $1 \times 1$ piece is labeled 1, next highest $1 \times 1$ piece is labeled 2, etc. where ties are broken by making the left-most piece come first. Then similarly do the same thing for the four $2 \times 1$ pieces, because in theory you may be able to get some permutations on them too, and if all permutations are possible, this would mean the overall multiplier on your number of boards would be $24^2$ in the worst case, which is considerably high compared to the number of boards you get after 39 moves.

Comment: it's comforting to know that probably my code works fine. the way you are suggesting seems the right one. the basic idea is to treat the same way pieces with the same size. probably it will be slower the first iterations, because comparing boards requires more computation, but I'm quite sure the game worth the candle

Answer (score 0):

Doubtful you're still working on your program, but I only just came across this because I'm presently writing a klotski solver program too and was also wondering if my numbers were, as you say, legit.

The magnitudes of the reachable positions shown in your output are close to my own program's, but the very first line of your output is curious. If I understand correctly, "step 1 new: 6 duplicated: 0" means that your algorithm found 6 new arrangements of the pieces by moving just one piece from the starting arrangement. It's easy to see that only the four smallest pieces can be moved in the very beginning. If each of these pieces is only permitted to move one space at a time, then only 4 new arrangements are possible. If additionally each of them is allowed to move two spaces in a row (such as moving the piece in the lower left corner two spaces to the right) while still counting as one "move", then I count a total of 8 possible new arrangements for the opening move. Indeed my program lists 8 reachable positions in the beginning. But your output says there are exactly 6 opening moves. Why 6?

Comment: You are right! That 6 in the first ouput line doesn't make sense. As you mentioned it should be a 4 or maybe a 5, if the initial position is included. Unluckily I don't have that specific code anymore, so I really can't help you with the numbers. What can I say is that I have completed a generic solver, that works quite well. For this specific puzzle, if I well remember, it takes less than a second to output the correct solution. The trick, as mentioned, is to consider different pieces with the same shape as the "same" piece when you snapshot a specific position.

Comment: Side note: with the solver also came an app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lucavallisa.freeme that includes 45 puzzles with solution sorted by the number of moves required. It's ad free, unless you want to check the animated solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look into that app. I'm also now modifying my program to make puzzle pieces of the same shape equivalent.